# Arch Linux booting in Emergency mode after installing another NVMe SSD

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot

So I recently installed another NVMe SSD into my computer and my Arch Linux will no longer boot. Here is the message I receive immediately after booting:

[image]

Here is a copy of what my `fstab` looks like:

[image]

In addition note that my system is dual boot with Windows, my boot loader is GRUB.

Also note that after looking into some forums there was an issue with LVM2 a few months ago, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/8y2xas/file_system_dependency_not_found_on_boot_yet_the/

I think what has happened is that my boot sequence is looking for `root`, `/home` and `swap` in `nvme0n1p*`, but installing another NVMe SSD has changed the SSD name of the drive that had Linux on it to `nvme1n1p*` (Note the change from 0 --> 1)! How do I tell the boot sequence to look in the correct partition on the correct drive?

Comment: -3 in 2 minutes, what is wrong with my question?

Comment: Well... Welcome on U&L! I did not downvote, but here are my thoughts: 1) Users on U&L expect questions to show research effort. Saying that you "forgot", "can't" or "don't remember" may be seen as a lack of such effort or, worse, as a refusal to make any effort. 2) Posting images is really [not well received](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/315749) and likely attract downvotes. 3) Even without these issues, questions that seem to ask for step by step guidance in troubleshooting usually don't score high.

Comment: I see, well that's a bit annoying since all I've been doing for the past 3 hours is reading forums about this. I don't know how to paste in the output from the command line since I am using a different computer to post this question, and I don't see how manually typing it out is a reasonable request. Regardless please see my edit as I think I found the problem I just don't know how to fix it!

Comment: (Actually, posting images in these circumstances is a valid exception to the general rule). I can't post an answer right now. Yes, your issue is probably in how your system is naming your devices. You should use `lsblk` and `blkid` to identify your current partitions, update your `fstab` using UUIDs - the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Identifying_filesystems) is your friend - and update your initramfs with `mkinitcpio -p linux`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually I have just done that, I checked the UUIDs and they all seemed correct using the commands you just mentioned. I tried directly editing the fstab file using nano and it worked! It was exactly the problem that I mentioned above, I simply changed the 0->1 after 'nvme' in the fstab file. However I want to ensure that this is a 'good' way to fix my problem, since I manually edited the fstab file.

Comment: That is almost a good way. Using UUIDs instead of device paths would be better. `fstab` is generated automatically (and optionally) only during the initial setup (by the `genfstab` install script). Otherwise it has to be edited manually. Without forgetting to regenerate the initramfs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem:

The drive and partition that had my arch linux installation on it was renamed from nvme0** to nvme1** after installing an additional nvme drive into my computer. I fixed my issue by simply directly editing my fstab file located in /etc using nano and manually changing the 0 --> 1, so that the boot sequence was actually looking in the correct location for my root, /home and SWAP partitions.

Hopefully this helps someone if they ever encounter this bizarre issue!